# I am getting runtime error 1004 in macro vba script in excel

Tags: excel, vba

**Can you help me with this problem**

I was making a macro to save the file as pdf in excel for a certain range of objects but face a runtime error

I got an error stating:

Runtime error 1004:
"Document Not Saved or maybe open or an error occurred while saving."

below is the code of it:

```
Sub AntigenReportSlip()

    Sheets("AntigenReportSlip").Select

    Dim filename As String
    Dim ChDir As String
    
    
    filename = Range("E9")

    ChDir = "D:\New Lab Report\AntigenReports\"

    Sheets("AntigenReportSlip").Range("$A$1:$U$33").ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,
     filename:= _
       ChDir & filename & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False,
     openAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error description, and at which line do you get the error?

Comment: What is the output, if you `debug.Print ChrDir & filename & ".pdf"`?

Comment: ChDir is a reserved VB/VBA word, you can't use it as a variable.

Comment: @MichaelO. It's bad practise, but you can (just tested)

Comment: Not sure, but are you missing a continuaion _ for the last line, or has it wrapped on here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Excel's **Range** class does not have a **ExportAsFixedFormat** method. However, **Workbook** class does.

This should help you

```
Sub AntigenReportSlip()
    
    ' Make sure this folder already exists
    Dim OutputFolder As String
    OutputFolder = "D:\New Lab Report\AntigenReports\"

    ' Get filename from E9 cell
    Dim filename As String
    filename = Sheets("AntigenReportSlip").Range("E9").value
    
    ' Compute full filename.
    ' Note: You should always store fullpath on a variable before using it.
    Dim fullFilename As String
    fullFilename = OutputFolder & filename

    ' Select cells range you would like to export
    Sheets("AntigenReportSlip").Range("$A$1:$U$33").Select
    
    ' Export selected range to PDF e present it
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=fullFilename, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, openAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

For further detailon **ExportAsFixedFormat** method, check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat